# Why is GET and POST request converting to OPTIONS request for cross-origin request for django rest framework and reactjs frontend?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I was looking to run my django and reactjs web application on mobile by connecting it to mac via hotspot, and changing the host to the ipaddress of the mobile. Thus, I changed my `localhost` to `192.168.43.19` in `/etc/hosts/`, and thus, my code is easily shared between mobile and mac, and I am able to run the localhost app on my mobile which is connected to mac via hotspot.

The backend is created in django rest framework. The problem is that all the get and post calls to the api created in the backend in django is being converted to `options` calls, and thus there are no returns, and the code is not working properly. While searching online, it said that the issue is because by default `Access-cross-origin-policy` is not allowed. To try handling the issue, I added the frontend url in `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` in the settings file of the django app, but it didnt work.

The `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` value set is the one, where the react code is being run. It is

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://192.168.43.194:3000',
    )
```

It will be really helpful, if someone could recommend me the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Which value you set for `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`?

Comment: Modified the question with your point

Comment: Have you install this package and add it into your `INSTALLED_APPS`? https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/, it should works. Set`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True` also considered as a solution for this case.

Comment: Adding that made it work. Thanks